# Why does Glue dynamic frame repartition create bigger file size than coalesce with same input data

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I have same input data and use repartition and coalesce function to write new parquet snappy files output.

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=df.repartition(nr_of_partition), # df.coalesce(nr_of_partition)
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"path": s3_path, "partitionKeys": ["year", "month"]},
    format="parquet",
    transformation_ctx="write_to_destination",
)
```

I noticed that the output files' size of coalesce are smaller than repartition.
I also check output row count, they are the same so I don't have duplicate data.
Why does Glue dynamic frame repartition create bigger file size than coalesce with same input data?

Thanks for reading.

Coalesce output:

[image]

Repartition output:

[image]

I would expect the total file size should be similar.

Comment: Is the `df` a spark Dataframe or a glue DynamicFrame?

Comment: Check [this note in the Spark scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/128c29035b4e7383cc3a9a6c7a9ab6136205ac6c/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L376) which makes me think the cause would be related to the number of nodes doing the work.  If there is a "shuffle" parameter, retry it with True and False on both and let's compare the differences.